# ASP.NET Core MVC - Connection strings and Data Libraries

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'll prefix this and say I'm new to .net core. I've been taken by surprise when trying to access a connection string I have in my appsettings.json file.

My solution has 2 projects, an MVC project and a Data Library. In the past with standard .net I was able to add a connection string into my web.config and access it from my data library like so:

```
namespace DataLibrary.DataAccess
{
    public static class SqlDataAccess
    {
        public static string GetConnectionString(string myConnection = "DemoDB")
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[myConnection].Connectionstring;
        }
    }
}
```

The "DemoDB" is the name of the connection string in the web.config. This doesn't work with .net core. I was wondering if someone could get me a step by step, talk to me like I'm 5, explanation of how I would get the connection string from my appsettings.json file in my MVC project into my DataLibrary?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to use data library in the MVC project, you should register it as a service in the main project.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
  public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterDataService(this IServiceCollection serviceDescriptors,IConfiguration configure) { 


        serviceDescriptors.AddDbContext<TestDBContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(configure.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringanme")));

        return serviceDescriptors;
    }

}
```

Then in the main MVC project's startup.cs method, you could use below codes:

```
services.RegisterDataServices(Configuration)
```

At last, you could add connection string into appsettings.json as below:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-ASPNETCoreIdentity-AE5A1558-8D92-4DA4-9A53-DDFB0BA30404;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-a-multi-project-net-core-database-solution-a69decdf8d7e).